# Remove html codes and spaces with php

Tags: php

I have a string:

```
$str = 'В        МАГАЗИНЕ        ПРАЗДНИК 
        &amp;amp;quot;МЕЖДУНАРОДНЫЙ        ДЕНЬ 
        ЗЕМЛИ&amp;amp;quot;     Скидки    на    самые актуальные товары уже ждут вас';
```

I need to remove `&amp` and other codes and spaces.

If I do:

```
htmlspecialchars(trim($str));
```

This is not helping me!

Answer (score 0):

How about a simple replace ?

```
$find = array('&amp;', 'quot;');
$myRes =trim(str_replace( $find ,'', $str));
```

Comment: but `quot`; ? how then?

Comment: answer  updated .. in str_replace you canuse an array for search

Comment: But can be global solution for all similar tags? Or I need search every tag and pass on array? Is difficult..

Comment: then you can use str_repalce ()  . ... this work .. and you can manage the array for find the string to substitution

Answer (score 0):

You can remove htmlspecialchars by html_entity_decode

```
html_entity_decode($str)
```

and for remove **qout** use regular preg_replace()